# Networkx dfs_edges not functioning as intended by professor

Tags: python, networkx, moodle

The expected output from dfs_edges(G, 4) is correct, but it's off by the position of one edges and I can't figure out why

Input:

```
G = nx.Graph()
edges = [(1,2),(1,3),(1,5),(2,5),(2,6),(3,4),(3,5),(4,5),(4,6),(4,7),(5,6)]
root = 4
G.add_edges_from(edges)
printGraph(G)
```

Expected Output:

```
DFS traversal from from 4 = [(4, 3), (4, 7), (3, 1), (1, 2), (2, 5), (5, 6)]
```

My Code:

```
import networkx as nx
def printGraph(G):
    print("DFS traversal from from 4 =", list(nx.dfs_edges(G,4)))
```

Result from code:

```
DFS traversal from from 4 = [(4, 3), (3, 1), (1, 2), (2, 5), (5, 6), (4, 7)]
```

The problem is the position of the (4, 7) edge, while I can manually place it where it should be, but that would mean it wouldn't work on the hidden text cases (Moodle)

Comment: It would seem that the result you are getting is the correct one. Depth-first should not look at (4,7) until the other branch came to an end. Maybe write an email to your professor and ask him about this.

Comment: I sent out an email simultaneously to posting this question, but since exams are coming up, he might not reply, but at the same time, if I can't finish this question, I can't do the final exam at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer got and expected are both correct, turns out he didn't want dfs_edges, he wanted the edges of the dfs tree instead, so this worked:

```
print("DFS traversal from from 4 =", nx.dfs_tree(G, root)).edges())
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your graph:

[image: Networkx graph with 7 nodes]

In a depth-first search starting at node 4, I would expect node 7 be be visited either first or last, not right after node 3. The output you're getting is valid for `dfs_edges`. The expected output is what's incorrect.